# actions=[[type=ACTION_OUTPUT action=[port=1 maxLen=0]];], as keywords to get_or_create in Bulbs

Tags: cassandra, titan, bulbs

I am using TitanGraphDB + Cassandra.I am starting Titan as follows

```
cd titan-cassandra-0.3.1
bin/titan.sh config/titan-server-rexster.xml config/titan-server-cassandra.properties
```

I have a Rexster shell that I can use to communicate to Titan+Cassandra above.

```
cd rexster-console-2.3.0
bin/rexster-console.sh
```

I want to program the Titan Graph DB from my python program.I am using bulbs package for that.

I create a vertex from python using bulbs as given below.

```
 fe1 = self.g.vertices.get_or_create('switch_dpid',switch_dpid,
          {'actionOutputPort':actionOutputPort,
           'switch_state':'FE_SWITCH_UPDATED',
           'matchInPort': MatchInPort,
           'type': 'flow_entry',
           'user_state':'FE_USER_ADD',
'actions': ['type':'ACTION_OUTPUT', 'action':[port=actionOutputPort maxLen=0];]})
```

This is giving me an error

```
  'actions': ['type':'ACTION_OUTPUT', 'action':[port=actionOutputPort maxLen=0];]}) 
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The output that I would expect from the Rexster console is as follows.

```
switch_dpid=00:00:00:00:00:00:02:05,
actionOutputPort=1,
switch_state=FE_SWITCH_UPDATED,
matchInPort=2,
flow_entry_id=0x4ee30a9400000012,
type=flow_entry,
actions=[[type=ACTION_OUTPUT action=[port=1 maxLen=0]];],
user_state=FE_USER_ADD
```

How do I program `actions` so that it is as above.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mixing up Groovy syntax with Python.

`actions` is a dictionary and `action` is a dictionary so in Python it should be:

```
'actions': {'type': 'ACTION_OUTPUT', 
            'action': {port: actionOutputPort,
                       maxLen: 0}}
```

Note it is usually more convenient (less quotes) to create Python dictionaries using the `dict` function:

```
'actions' = dict(type = 'ACTION_OUTPUT',
                 action = dict(port = actionOutputPort, 
                               maxLen = 0))
```